# KeyboardAvoidingView not working

Tags: react-native, native-base

```
<View style={Pagestyles.walletSendView}>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding'>
    <Form>
      <Item>
        <Input
            placeholder='Available Balance : XXX.XX / USD'
            onChangeText={(availableBalance) => this.setState({ availableBalance })}
            ref={(input) => this._availableBalance = input}
            returnKeyType='next'
            onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusInput('_sendToAddress')}
            value={this.state.availableBalance}/>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Input
            placeholder='Send to address'
            onChangeText={(sendToAddress) => this.setState({ sendToAddress })}
            ref={(input) => this._sendToAddress = input}
            returnKeyType='next'
            onSubmitEditing={() => this._focusInput('_numberOfCoinsToSend')}
            value={this.state.sendToAddress}/>
        <Icon active name='md-camera'/>
      </Item>
      <Button
          block
          onPress={() => this.onPress('')}
          style={{ marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#81a9cd' }}>
          <Text>Send</Text>
      </Button>
    </Form>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

Here I have used react native base for form fill up. But when I fill up field and click on next button from keyboard form doesn'scroll.

"Code repo": https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-24.0.0.tar.gz

"react": "16.0.0"

Comment: try wrapping it inside a `<ScrollView/>`

Comment: @jack can you add details of Form and Item tags? I have tried removing them. Its working.